# Applying the Schroedinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I hope this isn't a dumb question, but...

If we have two fixed sine waves, both of which have a frequency range of +1 to -1, with a ratio between the waves of wave(1):3 to wave(2): 1, what does the Schrodinger equation tell us (if anything) about the relationship between the waves?

Equally, if the waves are no longer fixed (ie, time dependent) and wave(1) has complete nine oscillations, what does Schrodinger predict about the relationship between the waves for oscillation number 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schroedinger equation is a dynamical equation that predicts the time evolution of a quantum system. Since it sounds like the time evolution of your system is externally imposed, the schroedinger equation doesn't make any predictions about it.

Your question is analogous to saying, "I define a particle trajectory in 1D, $x(t)$ for $0<t<T_{\mathrm{max}}$. What does $F=ma$ tell us about the trajectory? What does the trajectory do for $T_{\mathrm{max}} < t < T_{\mathrm{max}} + \Delta T$?"